# How to separate a column of cells with multiple values (delimited) into new columns and add a header

Tags: excel, vba, string

I have a spreadsheet containing a column that has data that looks like this:

Data;X=7.9;Y=9.1;Z=2;V=4;G=8

What I'm trying to do is essentially ignore 'Data;', then create new columns to the right with the associated values, in addition to adding the identifier (X,Y,Z,V or G) as the column header. Then delete the original column where the data string came from.

I have tried to do this with Text to Column, but it puts data in cells like this: X=7.9 etc.. When I wanted 7.9 in the field and so on per row, with the top (header) first cell contains X,Y,Z,V or G.

I suppose I may be able to utilize split text after, but at this point would prefer to do this in vba if possible.

I tried this, but couldn't get it to work with ; instead of |, but I'm not sure if it would add the column header as well, so probably not what I'm looking for.

```vb
DECLARE @t table (
   piped varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @t (piped)
  VALUES ('pipe|delimited|values')
       , ('a|b|c');

; WITH x AS (
  SELECT piped
       , CharIndex('|', piped) As first_pipe
  FROM   @t
)
, y AS (
  SELECT piped
       , first_pipe
       , CharIndex('|', piped, first_pipe + 1) As second_pipe
       , SubString(piped, 0, first_pipe) As first_element
  FROM   x
)
, z AS (
  SELECT piped
       , first_pipe
       , second_pipe
       , first_element
       , SubString(piped, first_pipe  + 1, second_pipe - first_pipe - 1) As second_element
       , SubString(piped, second_pipe + 1, Len(piped) - second_pipe) As third_element
  FROM   y
)
SELECT *
FROM   z
```

Comment: Why do you have SQL code here? You state Excel and VBA, have you tried VBA code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try the following code, using dictionaries. It's rather messy, and it could probably be done in simpler way, but it seems to work. Just edit the datarange line.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DataRange()
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim DataString As String
    Dim DataDictionary As Object 'SCRIPTING.DICTIONARY
    Dim TargetColumns As Object 'SCRIPTING.DICTIONARY
    Dim TargetColumn As Long
    Dim Key As String
    Dim TargetAddress As String

    Dim xlCurrentCalculation As XlCalculation
    Dim i As Long
    TargetColumn = 2

    xlCurrentCalculation = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'#############################################################################################
    Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A21") 'EDIT THIS LINE WITH ACTUAL DATA ADDRESS
'#############################################################################################
    Set DataSheet = DataRange.Parent
    Set TargetColumns = CreateObject("SCRIPTING.DICTIONARY")
    For Each c In DataRange
        DataString = CStr(c)
        Set DataDictionary = DataStringToDataDictionary(DataString)
        For i = 0 To DataDictionary.Count - 1
            Key = DataDictionary.keys()(i)
            If Not TargetColumns.exists(Key) Then
                TargetColumns.Add Key, TargetColumn
                TargetColumn = TargetColumn + 1
            End If
            TargetAddress = TargetColumns(Key) & c.Row
            DataSheet.Cells(c.Row, TargetColumns.Item(Key)) = DataDictionary.items()(i)
        Next i
    Next c
    For i = 0 To TargetColumns.Count - 1
        DataSheet.Cells(1, TargetColumns.items()(i)) = TargetColumns.keys()(i)
    Next i

    'Uncomment the following line to delete the column of the data containing the range.
    'It will create an offset in written data though
    'DataRange.EntireColumn.Delete
    Application.Calculate
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
Function DataStringToDataDictionary(DataString As String)

    Dim DataArray() As String
    Dim DataSubArray() As String
    Dim DataDictionary As Object 'SCRIPTING.DICTIONARY
    Dim Key As String
    Dim Value As String
    Dim i As Long

    DataArray = Split(DataString, ";")
    'We ignore first element of the array, as we assume it contains the word "Data"

    Set DataDictionary = CreateObject("SCRIPTING.DICTIONARY")
    For i = 1 To UBound(DataArray)
        DataSubArray = Split(DataArray(i), "=")
        Key = DataSubArray(0)
        Value = DataSubArray(1)
        DataDictionary.Add Key, Value
    Next i

    Set DataStringToDataDictionary = DataDictionary

End Function
```

Edit :

```
If the previous code does not work, you could also try the following :


Sub SplittingDataWithoutDictionary()
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim DataArray() As String
    Dim DataSubArray() As String
    Dim HeadersLabels() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim FirstWriteBackColumn As Long
    Dim Index As Long
    Dim Value As String

    Dim xlCurrentCalculation As XlCalculation

    xlCurrentCalculation = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


    HeadersLabels = Array("X", "Y", "Z", "V", "G")

    Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A20") 'Edit with the actual range you want to split
    Set DataSheet = DataRange.Worksheet
    FirstWriteBackColumn = 2 'Edit with the first column in which you want to write back data

    For Each c In DataRange
        DataArray = Split(CStr(c), ";")
        For i = 1 To UBound(DataArray)
            DataSubArray = Split(DataArray(i), "=")
            Index = FetchIndexInArray(HeadersLabels, DataSubArray(0))
            Value = DataSubArray(1)
            DataSheet.Cells(c.Row, FirstWriteBackColumn + Index) = Value
        Next i
    Next c
    For i = 0 To UBound(HeadersLabels)
        DataSheet.Cells(1, i + FirstWriteBackColumn) = HeadersLabels(i)
    Next i
    'Datarange.entirecolumn.delete
    Application.Calculation = xlCurrentCalculation
End Sub

Function FetchIndexInArray(StringArray() As Variant, LookFor As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(StringArray) To UBound(StringArray)
        If StringArray(i) = LookFor Then
            FetchIndexInArray = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and I get activex component can't create object, not sure why it has an issue with the line:


Set TargetColumns = CreateObject("SCRIPTING.DICTIONARY")

This is on Excel 2019, I'll try this on an earlier version tomorrow.

Comment: Are you using windows ? As far as I know, scripting.dictionary is not available on other operating systems.

Comment: I have edited my previous answer with a solution that does not use dictionaries. Be aware though that i assume the headers are restricted to the "X-Y-Z-V-G" values. Don't forget to edit the Datarange (cells in which you have the data that you want to split over several columns) and FirstWriteBackColumn (First column in which you start to write data).

Comment: Wow, your help is seriously beyond appreciated. Your original solution worked like a charm, you were correct, I was doing my testing on a mac and today tried on windows and it worked flawlessly. I seriously really appreciate your help and efforts on this. You are a good human being.